# Using Bootstrap 4, why isn't the navbar-icon-bar being shown?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive, hamburger-menu

I'm a newbie in bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to create a responsive navigation, so far I created a button with `class="navbar-toggler-icon"` which is supposed to present a hamburger-menu-like icon but it is not and I don't know why. Does anybody have any idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<!--==================  header  =====================-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
<!--================== end header  =====================-->


</main>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW these are the bootstrap 4 CDNs:
CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JQuery and JS:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @koder613 Yes, indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were unable to see the `hamburger` icon as the colouring of your navbar prevented you from seeing it.

You should add classes / styling for the colour of the `navbar` colour and the `navbar` background colour.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

You can see a codeply I created for you [here](https://www.codeply.com/p/NsSPnkYkBp)